# Google OAuth2 C# using refresh token and access token

Tags: c#, google-authentication

In the javascript API, one can do:

```
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
  YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);

// Retrieve tokens via token exchange explained above or set them:
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: 'ACCESS TOKEN HERE',
  refresh_token: 'REFRESH TOKEN HERE'
  // Optional, provide an expiry_date (milliseconds since the Unix Epoch)
  // expiry_date: (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
});
```

[source](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#example-upload-an-image-to-google-drive-from-a-readable-stream)

Can something similar be done with the C# API?
 I need this exact function!

I've been trying to find a way / method but haven't succeeded.

I'm using my own browser to get the `success code`, and I know how to convert this into the access and refresh tokens; however, I want to make use of the API, not a series of raw GET requests, for the rest of my work with Google's APIs.

Comment: is this for a Web Application or a Windows Application?

Comment: windows, the JS code works in Node.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure about it in Windows app. Hope someone can help you.

Comment: Check this 2 links: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples  and http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/